# Writing hex string into a binary file

Tags: python-2.7, utf-8, hex, hexdump, binascii

I am trying to write an hex string into a file using python 2.7 so that when opened with HxD I can retrieve the same hex values.
The following code works fine on multiple input strings, but when the string contains '0A' the writing is not working correctly.

```
import binascii
s = "0ABD"
f = open("output","w")
f.write(binascii.a2b_hex(s))
f.close()
```

After that open the file using HxD or online https://hexed.it/, you will find that '0D' is added before each '0A'.
I am reading these generated files using vb.net and still I am getting more bytes than expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are opening the file for writing in text mode, so newlines are converted to use system convention. In the case of Windows `0A` or `'\n'` gets converted to `0D 0A` or `'\r\n'`.

From the [python's documentation for open()](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#open) (**emphasis** added):

> If *mode* is omitted, it defaults to 'r'. The default is to use **text mode, which may convert `'\n'` characters to a platform-specific representation on writing and back on reading**. Thus, when opening a binary file, you should append `'b'` to the *mode* value to open the file in binary mode, which will improve portability.

Open the file in binary mode.

```py
f = open("output", "wb")
```